# Introduction to topological manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, online-resources

I'm searching for a freely available text that introduces topological and smooth manifolds. I don't need much, just their basic properties and a bit more motivation than the wikipedia articles offers. Maybe course notes of some course that covered them.

(Background: I skipped the classes where topological manifolds were introduced, and now I can't solve any problem where they appear, and I would like to change this before the exam ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very sure these links will be very useful.

http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/mfds.pdf

http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/MAT1300/week1.pdf

http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Smooth/c01.pdf

http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~azinger/mat531-spr10/lect1to5.pdf

Comment: @Benno. For good book, I will recommend Geometry of Differential Forms (Translations of Mathematical Monographs) by Shigeyuki Morita.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for it in our library.

Answer (score 1):

Lee's books are great. There is also a very nice book by Tu called [An Introduction to Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441973990) which is relatively new.

Comment: These books are not "freely available".